# Error message when starting Ruby on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

hope I can get some help with a problem I have been having. I am getting into Ruby on Rails and used a tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to try to get started with it. It says I need Sqlite3. I followed the steps up to the point where it says to use the ruby bin\rails server command in command prompt. However, when I try to do this, I get the following error message.

[image]

When I try to install Sqlite3, I use the x86 version for Windows, as I am using Windows 8.1.

I don't know what I am doing wrong...I am not even sure if the SQlite3 files are in the right place. I use command prompt to check if I have Ruby, Rails, and Sqlite3 all installed, which I do. I also know I have the SQlite3 Ruby gem installed. I have also added SQlite3 to my PATH system variable, but that doesn't seem to work either. I always get the same above error message no matter what I do.

Anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `gem uninstall sqlite3 (select all)`
`gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby` - that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a Linux VM on your Windows PC and start coding on it instead of on Windows. You'll keep encountering many issues in the future if you stick with Windows. Windows & ruby on rails don't go well together. So, it's better to go with some Linux flavor or preferably Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be learning RoR with the goal of ever doing anything serious in the future, here's the best advice I can give to someone starting out:  Buy a Mac.  NEVER try to use Microsoft for anything but Microsoft office...  you'll just end up so frustrated that you will give up.  RoR is NOT the toy to try "round peg, square hole" with.

Next, being that your on a Mac, NEVER use sqlite3.  You can easily use the correct database which is PostgreSQL.  Why is this important?

You're starting out.  Keep things very simple.  Get a free Heroku account, and install the CLI (for mac).  You can then do: "heroku local" to run your code locally (for building), and because it's Mac/PostgreSQL, when you go to push that code live, everything is the same (Heroku is going to be PostgreSQL) so you won't get lost for days trouble shooting the differences between where you're building the code, and where you're running the code.